# React Apollo Link - How to query a GraphQL server for an auth token outside of using <Query /> and <Mutation /> components?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo

After reading many articles on how to handle re-authentication for Apollo React, I have determined that I need to write my own logic to handle checking an expired JWT, refreshing the token, and then proceeding with an operation. I don't want to redirect to any kind of login page, from an error or wait until an error happens to refresh my token.

So I've followed the Apollo docs a bit to append a token to the header of every request. This works just fine:

```
const authLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  operation.setContext(({ headers = {} }) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

    // TODO: Check if token is expired. If so, fetch a new one from GraphQL server and THEN
    // move forward with operation

    // If token exists, add to headers
    if (token) {
      headers = { ...headers,authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "", };
    }

    return { headers };
  });

  return forward(operation);
});


const httpTopicsServiceLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4000/topics',
});

export const TopicsClient = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(httpTopicsServiceLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```

However, inside of `authLink` function, I want check if the token is expired to be able to send a GraphQL mutation to a server to refresh my token and THEN forward my operation. Since I've been doing all my GraphQL queries and mutations inside of the Apollo `<Query />` and `<Mutation />` components, I'm not sure how to make an isolated request to a GraphQL server to accomplish this kind of functionality. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

you can use TopicsClient to send quarries and mutations to the graphql server.

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {...}),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

client should be accessible inside the ApolloLink construction.